# Error says(in infoGather textbox) "an object reference is required for non static field ..."

Tags: c#, .net

This is the first time I encounter this error in a textbox

```
private static void infoGather_keydown(object sender,KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (username == null)
        {
            username = infoGather.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            password = infoGather.Text;
            if (username == "admin" && password == "admin")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("welcome");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the first time I encounter it in a `TextBox`

Comment: where are `username`,`password` and `infoGather` are defined? They are member variables and aren't static right?

Comment: yes it is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your TextBox `infoGatheran` is a member of an instance of the class, and is not `static`. Therefore you can't access it though a static function.

If you think about it it doesn't make sense - A static method belongs to the class and not a specific instance, therefore when you try to access a member of an instance - of which instance will it be?

To solve the specific error - is there any real reason to have this method `static`? If not just remove the `static` from the signature.